# Adding score to a yes/no game

Tags: javascript, html, variables, points

I'm creating a yes/no game and I have a variable score which is getting the id of the field that it has to be filled, the score needs to be updated each time the person chooses the right answer. The `if` is checking if the element photo is included in the array mentioned if it is, I have to add a point if, it is not I have to get the points back to 0.

How can I write the points if the variable is getting the id?

And how can I add a new point everytime the user gets the right answer?

I really can't get it. thanks.

```
var score = document.getElementById('score');

var foto;
var yesMeetup = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
var notMeetup = [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26];

var notButton = document.getElementById('no');
var yesButton = document.getElementById('yes');

var decisao = document.getElementById('decisao');

document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', verify);


function verify() {
  yesMeetup;
  notMeetup;

  if (yesButton) {

    if (yesMeetup.includes(foto)) {

      decisao.textContent = "You got it";
      decisao.style.display = "block";
      decisao.style.animation = "anim 1s";
      decisao.style.animationIterationCount = "1";
      parseInt(score.textContent) += "1";

    } else {

      decisao.textContent = "wrong";
      decisao.style.animation = "anim 1s";
      decisao.style.display = "block";
      decisao.style.animationIterationCount = "1";
      score.textContent = "0";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('#no').addEventListener('click', VerifyNo);

function VerifyNo() {
  yesMeetup;
  notMeetup;

  if (notButton) {
    if (notMeetup.includes(foto)) {

      decisao.textContent = "You got it";
      decisao.style.display = "block";
      decisao.style.animation = "anim 1s";
      decisao.style.animationIterationCount = "1";

    } else {
      decisao.textContent = "Wrong";
      decisao.style.display = "block";
      decisao.style.animation = "anim 1s";
      decisao.style.animationIterationCount = "1";

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share a working demo of this, preferably hosted on CodePen or JSFiddle, so we can clearly understand what's the problem?

Comment: @AmruthPillai Preferably, in a live snippet right here on SO.

Comment: its here https://codepen.io/brunoalvesdasilvabr/pen/MLNRpa        so the variable foto is updating a new photo with the random function and I have a lots of photos with the number 1.jpg, 2.jpg .....    but as I can not upload photos on codepen its not working now. but I think you can have an idea

Comment: @AmruthPillai We have Stacknippets built-in right here

Comment: sorry didn't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try to do to solve this is, keep a seperate score variable globally by declaring it at the top of the file: `var scoreVal = 0;`

Now, whenever the user gets one answer right, increment the score using `scoreVal++;`.  Finally, at the end of your verify function (outside all the if conditions) you can call `score.textContent = scoreVal;` as this would work even if the value has been updated or stays the same.

Here's a small working example, with the bare minimum:

```js
var score = 0;
document.getElementById('btn-right').addEventListener('click', right);
var scoreElem = document.getElementById('score');
scoreElem.textContent = score;

function right() {
  scoreElem.textContent = ++score;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="score"></h4>

<button id="btn-right">Right</button>
<button id="btn-wrong">Wrong</button>
```